# How to pass impl trait to a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, rust-tokio, ownership

I'm trying to pass the handler to a thread for each incoming request, I tried to wrap it inside an Arc but I'm getting the following error:

> the parameter type `impl ConnectionHandler` may not live long enough

**How to fix this issue ?**

```rust
impl TCPConnectionHandler {
    pub async fn set_handler(&self, handler: impl ConnectionHandler) {
        let arc_handler = Arc::new(handler);
        loop {
            let handler_clone = arc_handler.clone();
            match self.0.accept().await {
                Ok((mut stream, addr)) => {
                    let join_handle = tokio::task::spawn(async move {    
                        handler_clone.on_incoming_connection(&addr);
                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
                     // ❌ the parameter type `impl ConnectionHandler` may not live long enough
                    });
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    panic!("Error accepting connection")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you wrapped a value in an `Arc` doesn't mean it can't still contain non-static references.

For example, you *could* have a type, `MyCoolConnectionHandler<'a>`, which contains references. The type `Arc<`MyCoolConnectionHandler<'a>`>` still contains references.

If your implementations of `ConnectionHandler` do *not* contain references, you need to tell that compiler that it can make that assumption by constraining it to the `'static` lifetime:

```
pub async fn set_handler(&self, handler: impl ConnectionHandler + 'static) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: removing Arc resulted in the following error,
async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `handler`, which is owned by the current function.

Comment: I have no problem having Arc though, But it'd be nice if I understand how to update my code to allow removing Arc.

Comment: If your connection type is `Clone` then you could avoid `Arc` by cloning that instead of wrapping it. You'd need to change the type of the argument to: `impl ConnectionHandler + Clone + 'static`.